# Show an image on readthedocs and github

Tags: image, github, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, readme

In Sphinx you include an image at `docs/foo.png` with `.. image: foo.png`. But when GitHub renders the readme it tries to find the image relative to project root rather than relative to `docs/`, so it fails.

How do you make it work for both ReadTheDocs and Github? One answer is to just include the `githubusercontent.com` link, but that seems like a total hack.

Comment: A fully qualified URL is your best option. GitHub is not a good renderer for restructured text.

Comment: @StevePiercy Ok thanks